# After installing the NVIDIA drivers, the session with the Intel integrated card becomes slow

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, intel

I have installed the NVIDIA 390 drivers on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with my Geforce 1050 Ti, but after that if I choose the Intel integrated card from the NVIDIA settings, the boot of the Ubuntu session becomes very very slow. It never happened before on Ubuntu 17.10, and I don't know why it happens now and how to solve this problem.

EDIT: I also tried with the 396 drivers but with the same problem.

Comment: There seem to be some issues with Optimus in 18.04. At least it was discussed a week ago https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1035768/ubuntu-18-04-can-t-see-second-monitor/?offset=14

Comment: Is the nvida driver used? see it with `nvidia-settings`

Comment: If I use the NVIDIA driver everything goes fine, but if I use the Intel driver Ubuntu 18.04 LTS boots very slow although I have a SSD. It wasn't happening with Ubuntu 17.10, so I'm gonna read the discussion you linked.

Comment: I read the discussion and I tried solving my problem in other ways, but with no success.